# Problem with apache2 server

Tags: apache-httpd

So I am having a problem with my apache2 server sharing a file.  I am on ParrotSec OS 4.11 debian.  Anyhow, when I create a file alexa.exe and place it in /var/www/html directory and then start *service apache2 start*  Then on my windows computer I go to my Parrot machines IP http://192.168.1.218/alexa.exe and it does not work.  The response says cannot reach this page.  Make sure you have the right webaddress.

I tried it from my cellphone and it timed out.  However, if I try it from my parrot machine it works.  I tried turning off my firewall on my parrot machine and it still does not work.  I cannot see why this should not work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

It is not a fresh apache install, however I can reach the default page and the firewall is gufw a gui which I turned off.

I have know problem getting apache to work on Kali and it should basically be the same on parrot im guessing.  I may just try doing a fresh install.  There is no reason it should not work after that, but if anyone has any other ideas I would be happy to hear.

Comment: Is it a fresh apache install ? Can you get the default apache page ? How did you disable the firewall and what firewall do you use ?

Comment: ParrotSec isn't meant for use as a web server. Like Kali Linux, It's for penetration testing, etc and assumes that you already have a working knowledge of Linux. If you are having trouble with getting a system to allow access to a web server, then it's not the right OS for you as there is a plenty of other basic troubleshooting that you'll need to do.